# Application Pool parando no IIS7

Tags: iis-7

Instalei o Redmine no IIS 7 no Windows 7 + MySql, porém sempre que tento acessar a URL local a pagina aparece com erro 503, descobri que isso esta ocorrendo porque o Application Pool esta parando em meio a solicitação da página.

A Instalação foi feita através do `Web Platform Installer` do `IIS` e para isso tive que referenciar o feed de aplicativos da Helicon que parece ser a única que faz com que o Redmine apareça no Web Platform Installer, neste link [Helicon Zoo installation](http://www.helicontech.com/zoo/install.html)

No log do windows aparece o seguinte erro:

> A DLL de Módulos 'C:\Zoo\NativeModule\HeliconZoo_x64.dll' não pôde ser
>   carregada devido a um problema de configuração. A configuração atual
>   oferece suporte somente para o carregamento de imagens criadas para
>   uma arquitetura de processador AMD64

Como posso resolver isso ou qual a causa disso?

> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

[image: Log Windows]

[image: IIS]

Comment: Algum erro crítico na inicialização da aplicação. Cheque o Log do Windows para saber o que realmente aconteceu.

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta para ficar mais clara.

Answer (score 1):

A sua imagem possui a resposta para seu problema:

> A DLL de módulos C:[ilegivel] Não pode ser carregada (...) arquitetura de processador AMD64.

Você está tentando carregar um Assembly compilado para um outro tipo de processador.

Comment: Essa informação não esta disponível na pagina da Helicon, imaginei que fosse um pacote para qualquer arquitetura, existe uma forma de resolver isso ou algum outro link que tenha um feed de apps que traga o RedMine para o Web Installer do IIS?

Comment: @PauloRoberto Infelizmente não conheço o WebMine para lhe dar uma resposta conclusiva. =/